# How to call SimpleImputer.fit_transform() on entire data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, transform

I was going through Kaggle's Machine Learning Curriculum. On coming to the topic of handling missing data using imputation, I came up with the following problem while trying to code along.

I was unable to call SimpleImputer.fit_transform() on the entire dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
original_data = pd.read_csv('melb_data.csv')
my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
data_with_imputed_values = my_imputer.fit_transform(original_data)
```

**In the last line was below error**

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'